# Change the quiver arrows color by point meta

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

In PGFPlots reference page 93 (version 1.14), an example shows how to change the arrow line width according to the point meta.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% define some constants:
\def\U{1}
\def\V{2*x}
\def\LEN{(sqrt((\U)^2 + (\V)^2)}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,
title=Thickness indicates ‘‘strength’’.
]
\addplot[blue,
point meta={\LEN},
quiver={
u={(\U)/\LEN}, v={(\V)/\LEN},
scale arrows=2,
every arrow/.append style={
line width=2pt*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000
},
},
-stealth,samples=15,
] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to change the arrow color rather than the line width according to the point meta by mapping `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` to colormap. I have look up the pgfplots reference but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that, you only need to add `color=mapped color` at the appropriate place (have a look at the comments in the code).

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % needed if you only want to color the arrow tips
    % (but I personally use the new/advanced arrows all the times)
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % define some constants:
        \def\U{1}
        \def\V{2*x}
        \def\LEN{sqrt((\U)^2 + (\V)^2)}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal image,
        title=Thickness indicates ‘‘strength’’.
    ]
        \addplot[
%            % of course you don't need to provide a color here, if you want
%            % to color the whole arrow
%            blue,
            point meta={\LEN},
            quiver={
                u={(\U)/\LEN}, v={(\V)/\LEN},
                scale arrows=2,
                every arrow/.append style={
                    line width=2pt*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000,
                    % ------------------------------------------------
                    % if you want to color the whole arrows, just add
                    color=mapped color,
                    % ------------------------------------------------
                },
            },
            -Stealth,
%            % -------------------------------------------------------
%            % if you want to color the arrow tip only, use this one
%            {-Stealth[mapped color]},
%            % -------------------------------------------------------
            samples=15,
        ] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]